# cross domain jquery ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, web-applications

I am sending ajax request to a url http://json-cricket.appspot.com/score.json
by the code

```
var url="http://json-cricket.appspot.com/score.json";
$.get(url, function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}, 'json');
```

and this is not working, but if I add '`?callback=?`' to the url, then it will work. i.e.

```
var url="http://json-cricket.appspot.com/score.json?callback=?";
$.get(url, function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}, 'json');
```

Then it will work.

Both url will give the output. Only the difference is the the latter one will wrap the results on `?(result)`.

For my knowledge, can anyone explain me what is happening? It was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140978/jquery-getjson-not-working-on-url).

Any link for further study would be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because it is a cross-domain ajax request.

For more info, you can have a look at the wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP