# Cross-domain Jquery AJax jsonp

Tags: jquery, cross-domain

I'm building both an application and the server (unfortunately on different domains)

On the application I have:

```
$.ajax({
  url: BASE_URL + "api/create",
  type: "get",
  async: false, // why do I need this
  dataType: "jsonp",
  data: {
    "auth_token": "cBQHASwKszsW4e75unK6"
  }, 
  error: function(error) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
  },
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

I know that the server is returning (when I go to it in a browser):

```
jQuery1910041686943266540766_1365730282085({"error":"User does not exist","status":400})
```

(which is correct data)

However, the ajax request fails and is listed as status "failed" and type "pending"

I'm not sure what's going on here

---

I have also tried:

```
 $.getJSON(BASE_URL + "api/create?auth_token=cBQHASwKszsW4e75unK6&callback=?", function(data) {
   alert(JSON.stringify(data));
 });
```

which also failed

Comment: You got `jQuery1910041686...` without specifying callback function var? What address you got in `Net` tab in `Firebug`?

Comment: `async` can't be false for jsonp as far as I know. Not saying it's related to your issue, but a cross-domain jsonp request adds a script tag and that is async.

Comment: localhost:3000/api/create?callback=jQuery19101939692951273173_1365751304024&auth_token=cBQHASwKszsW4e75unK - to answer the first question, the callback argument is apparently added by jquery

Comment: I set async to true and it still fails. also added a 10 second wait and it still fails

Comment: Sorry, I meant I tried true

Comment: Hanging like this, I'd guess jQuery is the one cancelling the request.. perhaps origin control issue as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/14915325/1613589 ? You server obviously replies correctly to jsonp requests, so it's something the $.ajax did not like (that's why you don't see the actual response form the server in the Network monitor console in the browser). Never tried it with jsonp but perhaps http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/ global event (or even preFilter) can hopefully help you see the exact response.. Still, nothing in error console?

Comment: 1. I have added the headers in the server 2. ajaxComplete does not fire 3. here are all ajax requests sent by my browser (from preFilter) http://pastebin.com/W8tSMeTg

Answer (score -1):

For this you need to crate a proxy page.
Ex : proxy.php

calling the request directly call proxy.php via ajax

Lets know it works for u.

Steps :
1. create a new page proxy.php
2. Use CURL or File_get_contents to fetch the data from the external URL.
3. Call the proxy.php via ajax in place of cross domain URL.

Comment: Don't understand how a page called proxy.php will help

Comment: @deep2mail — It's using JSON-P. There shouldn't be any need to involve a proxy.

Comment: What ever data u are using u cant directly call the cross domain URL

Comment: Yes you can - JSONP is exactly the thing to use cross-domain and it is clever as hell and uses methods almost any browser will conform to. Read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP