# How to build json cross domain call php

Tags: javascript, php, json

i'm new in json cross domain. here is my problem. I want to call php with json cross domain, but still get error. example code to call:

```
    $(function() {
        var doc = urls;
        $( "#origin" ).autocomplete({
            source: ''+doc+'book/server_book_from.php',
            select: function( event, ui ) 
            {
                $( "#origin" ).val( ui.item.label );
                $( "#take_book_from" ).val( ui.item.code );
                $( "#take_book_from_label" ).val( ui.item.label );
                return false;
            }
        });

        $( "#nation" ).autocomplete({
            source: ''+doc+'book/server_book.php',
            select: function( event, ui ) 
            {
                $( "#nation" ).val( ui.item.label );
                $( "#take_book_to" ).val( ui.item.code );
                $( "#take_book_to_label" ).val( ui.item.label );
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

How can I use json to run a PHP for cross domain??

Thanks.

Comment: First step use the url, second step, make sure the other domain support CORS

Comment: You can add a proxy and call ajax in this
http://stackoverflow.com/a/11605168/2210993

Comment: To get CORS working you need the **server** to send out an access control header.  If everyone is allowed, tbis can be very simple.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3076648/103081

Comment: In the code snippet I don't see any JSON.  How is JSON involved?  With CORS you are better off calling any JSON 'text/plain' instead of 'application/json' to avoid CORS preflight requirements for "non-simple" requests.

Answer (score 0):

The [`SOP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) (same origin policy) relies on the protocol, host and port to be the same. [`CORS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) allowed a different origin to request a document (see http://enable-cors.org/ for how to do this, and why).

The alternative is [`JSONP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). `JSONP` will allow you to use callbacks to circumvent SOP.

Comment: Other way is to use your domain as proxy :)