# load json file in an object variable

Tags: jquery, json

I have a jquery function which looks like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var doubleEliminationData = {}
$(function () {
    $('div#doubleElimination').bracket({
        init: doubleEliminationData
    })
})  
</script>
```

and the content of the variable doubleEliminationData is in a JSON file. When i copy/paste the code in the JSON file in the variable it works just fine. But i need to load it from the JSON file because on an other website i can change the content in this file. I tried $.get, $.getjson and $.ajax to get the content of the file but it doesnt work. I hope you can help withe this.
How do i load the content of the JSON file into the var doubleEliminationData?

Comment: how about giving your fiddle?

Comment: You're going to run into issues because you sound like you are doing a Cross-domain-request which is by default not allowed.  There are ways around it like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549068/json-how-do-i-make-cross-domain-json-call

Comment: Can you explain what "Doesnt work mean?". And btw do you have control over the server that hosts the JSON file?

Comment: Doesnt work = the page loads but the function is not executed.If i write the json file content manually in the variable the function is executed

Comment: I have control over the server

Comment: I request the json file from a subdomain

Comment: Thanks to all of you. Its working now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this with Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: urlPathToYourFile,
    data: data,
    success: successFn
});
```

or you can use shorthand Ajax function [jQuery.getJson()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

```
$.getJSON("yourJsonFile.json", function(data) {
    console.log(data);//output your data to console
});
```

Comment: hi. the $.getJSON worked just fine. I also had to request the json file from the main domain and not the subdomain. Is it possible to do this request in a function? When I try to put it in a  function, the request is not send. Any idea?