# how to run json parsing from php-url in html java script in apache /var/www/demo.html

Tags: php, apache, parsing, ubuntu

I have two ubuntu 12.03 OS, machines 1. server machine 2. my device

1. SERVER MACHINE:

   1. created DB TABLES in Mysql'
   2. PLACED ALL PHP files in /var/www/gps/*
   3. my website : All html files placed /var/www/demo1.html
      if i run my webapp in browser with ip : [http://mywebsite/demo1.html] can run as i wish. In demo1.html i am parsing the json format data from php url provided like below.

      ```
      var jqxhr1 = $.getJSON("http://mywebsite/gps/showGPS.php",

             function(data) {

                longi=data.longi; 
                lati=data.lati; 

              }).done(function() { 

       })
      .fail(function() {  /*alert("unable to show MAP");*/ })
      .always(function(){ /*alert("second complete");*/ });
       jqxhr1.complete(function(){ 

             //my stuff
          });
      ```

with this i can run webapp demo1.html prefectly in server.

but what i want is i am taking demo1.html file to my device and do some editings when ever required and upload to server. but when i am trying to run demo1.html from [http://localhost/demo1.html] [placed  demo1.html in my device /var/www/demo1.html ] can not able to parse the data from which the URL provided [http://mywebsite/gps/showGPS.php]

Showing parsing Error !!!!!

May i know What is the Problem of not parsing server URL ????

Any Configurations Required????

Answer (score 0):

i think its a cross domain problem.. you might want to take a look here: [JSON: How do I make cross-domain JSON call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549068/json-how-do-i-make-cross-domain-json-call)