# Empty responseText after GET Http Request with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web-services, http, get

i try to get text from a Http Get Request:

This is a small web service to correct texts.

```
http://193.196.7.26/cgi-bin/ColorError-line.pl?arg_childText=Ich%20gehe%20in%20die%20schule.&arg_errors=MOR_GrS;MOR_KS&arg_corrText=Ich%20gehe%20in%20die%20Schule.
```

When i call the service with a browser (f.e. Chrome) i see the corrected text.

Now i try this in Javascript:

```
var http2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url1 = "http://193.196.7.26/cgi-bin/ColorError-line.pl?arg_childText=Ich%20gehe%20in%20die%20schule.&arg_errors=MOR_GrS;MOR_KS&arg_corrText=Ich%20gehe%20in%20die%20Schule."
http2.open("GET", url, false);
http2.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/plain");
http2.send(null);
var temp = http2.responseText;
```

But responseText is empty. Any idea?

Comment: Did you mean `http2.open("GET", url1, false);`?

Comment: Is that your domain? There is no Access-Control-Allow-Origin so cross-origin requests will fail.

Comment: @Pietu:
Ohh i'm a idiot ..
but now i get a error message:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://193.196.7.26/cgi-bin/ColorError-line.pl?arg_childText=Ich%20gehe%20in%20die%20schule.&arg_errors=MOR_GrS;MOR_KS&arg_corrText=Ich%20gehe%20in%20die%20Schule.. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: You need to call a server side script on your domain that downloads from that url and returns the result.

Comment: @Alex:
No this isn't my domain.
Can only the host of the webservice fix this problem?

Comment: Yes, or make a script to do it; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549068/json-how-do-i-make-cross-domain-json-call

Answer (score 0):

You must set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

In `.htaccess`:

```
<Files "ColorError-line.pl">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
</Files>
```

**or** print this header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

**This will allow cross-domain access from *any* domain, not just yours.** To only allow your domain only, you should set it to

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yourdomain.com
```

without the slash in the end, but then you must remember to change it if your domain changes. This also applies to the `.htaccess` version.

**Update:** Also, you could create a proxy script to do it, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549068/json-how-do-i-make-cross-domain-json-call). However, I recommend that you filter the URL sent to the proxy, or someone could create lots of excess traffic to your site by downloading big files with it.

Comment: You should point out for anyone unfamiliar with CORS that this will allow cross-dom access from anyone

Comment: But why can i call the service with any Browser but not so easy with Javascript? That makes no sense to me.

Comment: @SimonHilner Because the pages (here your own page) are given less permissions than the user; the pages may not load any page they want (here the service) but the user (of course :D) can.

Comment: Maybe someone of you knows a better way to get what i want. I have no chance to call the owner of the server in the next time.

Comment: @SimonHilner There is another method in the answer.