# Custom Map draw with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Can anybody say, how can I draw custom MAP vector map (dynamic) with using mongodb's Geo-spatial data?

Or I look for Map maker with using mongoDB.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB's default data storage is now GeoJSON, see [the GeoJSON docs](http://geojson.org/). This format, being an extension of JSON, naturally plays very well with Javascript. There are direct GeoJSON loaders in  [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#load_geojson), [OpenLayers](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13/examples/geojson.html) and in [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html), three of the better known Javascript mapping libraries out there. Both OpenLayers and Leaflet are open source, so you can view the source to see how it works and extend as you wish.
You will have to write something to transmit the GeoJSON from MongoDB to the client and you might have to deal with cross domain issues, depending on your setup, see [JSON: How do I make cross-domain JSON call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549068/json-how-do-i-make-cross-domain-json-call) for possible solutions.