# JQuery cross domain getJSON ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, cross-domain

I am trying to consume this `JSON` web service: http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/significant_week.geojson

I have tried the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    jsonp: false,
    success: function() { alert("Success"); },
    error: function() { alert('Failed!'); }});
}
```

I get the following error in chrome :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load ...earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/significant_week.geojson. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I have seen all the suggestions for changing `datatype` to `jsonp` but this doesn't work in my case because this service does not provide `jsonp` data. 
Is there is any other way to parse this data with JavaScript?

Comment: You are out of luck here. You can set up server proxy and request it instead.

Comment: Looks that to use server proxy on the same domain is the only way. See this answer for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/11605168/1105860

Comment: "because this service does not provide `jsonp` data" - have you tried this url: http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/significant_week.geojsonp

Comment: Thank you all for the help. The proxy method didnt work for me. But as Stephan Muller said this service provides jsonp data and i haven't realized it. So my problem solved.