# Submitting Form with non standard POST data format

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I have a standard HTML form embedded in a PHP page that posts to an external Job Application API hosted and managed by a third party.  The problem is that their form doesn't expect a load of $_POST parameters as usual, but wants one single $_POST parameter ('params') in the following format:

```
params="Prop2:title;Prop4:lastname;Prop6:firstname;"
```

And so on - there's about 30 fields.

How can I take the form inputs and convert to the single long string?  Does this need some form of intermediary step between submit and post (In which case how would I put in the intermediary step?) or am I missing something more fundamental here?

The example form below works with a test textarea input with the required params presubmitted, but obviously ignores the actual firstname lastname inputs.

```
<form id="#applicationForm" method="POST" action="https://www.example.com/eternal-api">

  <input id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Last name (Required)" class="input-xlarge" required="">
  <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First Name (Required)" class="input-xlarge" required="">
  <textarea name="params" rows="2" cols="150">Prop4:Test_lastname;Prop6:test_firstname;</textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Application" class="btn btn-success">

</form>
```

To confuse matters, some of the inputs are upload fields, but I'll worry about that next!

Comment: You could use a webrequest: http://php.net/manual/en/httprequest.send.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try a very basic approach:

```js
$('#applicationForm').submit(function(e) {

  var params = '';

  $(this).find('input, textarea, select').filter('[name]').each(function() {

    if ($(this).is('textarea')) {

      params += $(this).val();
      return;

    }

    params += $(this).attr('name') + ':' + $(this).val() + ';';


  });

  $(this).append($('<input>', {

    type: 'hidden',
    name: 'params',
    value: params

  }));
  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="applicationForm" method="POST" action="https://www.example.com/eternal-api">

  <input id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Last name (Required)" class="input-xlarge" required="">
  <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First Name (Required)" class="input-xlarge" required="">
  <textarea name="params" rows="2" cols="150">Prop4:Test_lastname;Prop6:test_firstname;</textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Application" class="btn btn-success">

</form>
```

I loop trough every element and gather the values. Then I append an hidden input with your values

Comment: Great answer - thankyou.  Only problem is it takes both values for Radio Buttons, but I've replaced these with Selects which work fine.  Thanks very much

Comment: Yes I forgot about radio buttons. You can use them when specify that only selected radio buttons are allowed (use :checked as selector)

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript to pre-process form data, and then post it to their url via Ajax. To get the data:

```
params="firstname:"+$("#firstname").val() + "; lastname: " + ....
```

to post it, you can use ajax POST..

```
$.Post(url, {data})
```

More details can be found at [jquery POST](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) documentation

Comment: Thanks for that, very helpful.  Can I post to an external server using ajax?  I was under the impression that it had to be on the same server?

Comment: Not necessary, friend! Unless the "other server" has restrictions for cross domain requests, I guess it should not be any problem. If you find the answer correct, you can mark it as accepted .. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is JSON?
If yes, use jQuery. [jquery ajax doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Why does it have to be in jQuery?

Comment: I did look at that, but as it's not hosted on the same server, I don't think I can use ajax?

Comment: Why jQuery - Simple, well documented :). Other server is not a problem.

Comment: Other server  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141531/cross-domain-jquery-ajax-request